# installing ceres in ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ceres-solver

Im trying to install ceres solver in ubuntu 16 as follows. When i try to test make "make test" it gives me the error no tests were found! Can someone please explain what i am doing wrong?

I am following the official ceres-solver installation instructions as in:

http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html

```
niraj@niraj-ThinkPad-L380-Yoga:~/ceres/ceres-bin$ sudo make -j3
[ 88%] Built target ceres
[ 91%] Built target helloworld_numeric_diff
[ 91%] Built target curve_fitting
[ 92%] Built target helloworld_analytic_diff
[ 93%] Built target curve_fitting_c
[ 95%] Built target ellipse_approximation
[ 95%] Built target helloworld
[ 96%] Built target rosenbrock
[ 98%] Built target robust_curve_fitting
[ 99%] Built target simple_bundle_adjuster
[100%] Built target sampled_function
niraj@niraj-ThinkPad-L380-Yoga:~/ceres/ceres-bin$ sudo make test
Running tests...
Test project /home/niraj/ceres/ceres-bin
No tests were found!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

What cmake call did you use? the log indicates that you built the library and examples but none of the tests.